# Fixed Columns to Row

Tags: vba, excel

Have data spread across columns

Want to keep the first three columns fixed (columns a, b and c).

And convert columns from four onward into new rows (columns d --> last column where there is a value).

Example:
[image]

The colours from columns D -->onwards are NOT always green, blue, black red, etc.... they vary depending on the data loaded in from a power query table.

This is how I want the data to look:

[image]

Notice how columns A, B and C are fixed with the same info and only columns D onwards is recreating a new "row".

I've been trying to adapt a VBA script from a previous post on here, but I'm having some complications. I'm also trying to keep it on the sheet that the data is currently on, not create a new sheet. If it is easier to just create a new sheet.. then I can work with that.. Script:

```
Sub ColumnTorow()

  Dim maxRows As Double
    Dim maxCols As Integer
    Dim data As Variant
    maxRows = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).row
    maxCols = Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column

    data = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(maxRows, maxCols))

    With ActiveSheet

        Dim rRow As Long
        rRow = 2

        Dim row As Long

        row = 2
        Dim col As Integer

        Do While True

            col = 2
            Do While True
                If data(row, col) = "" Then Exit Do 'Skip Blanks


                .Cells(rRow, 1).Value = data(row, 1)


                .Cells(rRow, 2).Value = data(row, col)

                rRow = rRow + 1
                If col = maxCols Then Exit Do 'Exit clause
                col = col + 1
            Loop

            If row = maxRows Then Exit Do 'exit cluase
            row = row + 1
        Loop

    End With
End Sub
```

This is just an example code that I was provided with and I'm trying to modify... It might not even be the correct solution to this problem but figured I would post it anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, since I did this yesterday, I got it together fairly quickly:

```
Sub ColumnToRow()

  Dim maxRows As Double
    Dim maxCols As Integer
    Dim data As Variant
    maxRows = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).row
    maxCols = Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column

    data = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(maxRows, maxCols))

    Dim newSht As Worksheet
    Set newSht = Sheets.Add

    With newSht

        .Cells(1, 1).Value = data(1, 1)
        .Cells(1, 2).Value = data(1, 2)
        .Cells(1, 3).Value = data(1, 3)
        .Cells(1, 4).Value = data(1, 4)

        Dim writeColumn As Double
        writeColumn = 1

        Dim writeRow As Double
        writeRow = 2

        Dim row As Double
        row = 2

        Do

            writeColumn = 1

            Dim col As Double
            col = 4

            Do While True
                If data(row, col) <> "" Then
                    Dim firstColData As String
                    firstColData = data(row, 1)
                    .Cells(writeRow, writeColumn) = firstColData
                    writeColumn = 2


                    Dim secondColData As String
                    secondColData = data(row, 2)
                    .Cells(writeRow, writeColumn) = secondColData
                    writeColumn = 3

                    Dim thirdColData As String
                    thirdColData = data(row, 3)
                    .Cells(writeRow, writeColumn) = thirdColData
                    writeColumn = 4

                    .Cells(writeRow, writeColumn).Value = data(row, col)

                    writeColumn = 1
                    writeRow = writeRow + 1

                End If

                If col = maxCols Then
                    Exit Do 'Exit clause
                End If
                col = col + 1

            Loop

            If row = maxRows Then
                Exit Do 'exit cluase
            End If
            row = row + 1

        Loop While True


    End With
End Sub
```

[image: results for data]

Comment: I should note though, that I programmed it so requires "Header 4" through "Header 11" titles, but you can probably figure out how to rid that part, since it ignores it anyway

Comment: absolutely amazing. going to try it out rn and adjust as needed.

Answer (score 1):

consider this code.

```
Sub TransData()
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, j As Integer, k As Integer
    vDB = Range("a1").CurrentRegion

    For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        For j = 4 To UBound(vDB, 2)
            If vDB(i, j) <> "" Then
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 4, 1 To n)
                For k = 1 To 3
                    vR(k, n) = vDB(i, k)
                Next k
                vR(4, n) = vDB(i, j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Sheets.Add
    Range("a1").Resize(1, 4) = Array("Item", "Amount", "Price", "Color")
    Range("a2").Resize(n, 4) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
End Sub
```